# Select distinct value from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my SQL Server database, I have a table with this sample data:

```
ID  lastDate
---------------
1   null
1   null
1   null
2   null
2   2018-12-14
2   null
3   null
4   null
4   2018-12-14
4   2018-12-14
```

I need to retrieve distinct ID whose lastDate value is null (i.e 1 & 3 only )

Please let me know the SQL query for this

Answer (score 3):

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having max(lastdate) is null;
```

Or:

```
having count(lastdate) = 0
```